# Select max date inside a list according by user id

Tags: linq, list, group-by, max

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int PersonId {get;set;}
    public string University {get;set;}
    public string Department {get;set;}
    public DateTime GraduatedDate {get;set;}
}

List<Person> list = new List<Person>();
list.Add(new Person { 1, 1, "Shota Rustavelli University", "Computer Science BS", "10.12.2005" });
list.Add(new Person { 2, 1, "Shota Rustavelli University", "Computer Science MS", "10.12.2005" });
list.Add(new Person { 3, 2, "Tblisi State University", "Mathematics BS", "10.12.2004" });
list.Add(new Person { 4, 3, "Shota Rustavelli University", "Economics BS", "10.12.2006" });
list.Add(new Person { 5, 3, "Tblisi State University", "Economics MS", "10.12.2006" });
list.Add(new Person { 6, 1, "Georgian Technical University", "Mathemetics Phd", "10.12.2009" });



foreach(var item in (list.GroupBy(m=> new{m.PersonId,m.University,m.Department})).Max(m=>m.GraduatedDate))
{
    item.PersonId
    item.University
    item.Department
}
```

How i get last graduted university and department according by PersonId use below structure.I have tried to use LINQ GroupBy and Max but i got error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Max(m=>m.GraduatedDate)` will bring you just that: the max value of `GraduatedDate` in the set. In your case it does not compile, because you apply it to a collection of itemsthat do not have a `GraduatedDate` property.

In order to get the last graduation per person, you could use the following LINQ query:

```
    var results = 
        list
        .GroupBy(m => m.PersonId)
        .Select(g => new {
            PersonId = g.Key,
            LastGraduation = g.OrderByDescending(p => p.GraduatedDate).First()
        });
```

The results can be displayed afterwards like this, for example:

```
    foreach(var r in results){
        Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}", 
            r.PersonId,
            r.LastGraduation.University,
            r.LastGraduation.Department);
    }
```

Here's an ideone snippet that shows a running version of this: http://ideone.com/em4Ygq

*Please note that I changed the `GraduatedDate` to `string`, to better match the way you initialized the list. I should be declared as `DateTime` and be initialized accordingly.*

Comment: Sory my problem still

Answer (score 1):

While you can use GroupBy and Max to return the latest person entry, it's easier and often faster to use MoreLINQ's [MaxBy](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/wiki/OperatorsOverview) operator to return the element with the largest predicate:

```
IEnumerable<Person> personEntries=list.GroupBy(p => p.PersonId)
            .Select(g => g.MaxBy(p => p.GraduatedDate));
```

You can add the MoreLINQ library as a [single NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/) or you can add just the source code for the operators you want, eg [MaxBy](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MoreLinq.Source.MoreEnumerable.MaxBy/)

The reason these operators are faster than GroupBy and ordering is that the MaxBy/MinBy operators do not sort the elements of a list but simply walk over all the items keeping only a reference to the largest/smallest item they have encountered. This is much faster than sorting.

In PLINQ scenarios MaxBy/MinBy are indispensable as sorting would introduce locks and synchronization that could make your PLINQ query run slower that the sequential version.